# AngularJS - Filter HTML character references

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a set of JSON responses/results that i display to the front-end.

Some of these contain HTML character codes, for example:

```
<b>Some Text</b>
```

Rather thank using ngSanitize, can i create a custom filter that converts the HTML tags?

So the above would display as:

> **Some Text**

Comment: Yes you can, just more likely it takes some time

Comment: Why would you want to do that rather than using the already given directive?